# ngOnChange doesnt trigger second time when model change on ngOnInit

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have written a code in **CHILD component**

```
@Input() public status: Array<KeyValue<FlowStep>>;
@Input() public logs: Observable<Array<WorkFlow>>;
constructor() {

}
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    //throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    let stat : any = changes["status"];
    debugger;

}
```

and trying to call the `ngOnChange` for every time input model change.
The Problem is `ngOnChange` calls first time , after that when i try to change model it doesnt hit the `ngOnChange`

In **parent component**

```
     ngOnInit() {
     //`ngOnChange` CALLS ON BELOW LINE INITIALIZE ONLY 
     this.fileStatus = new Array<KeyValue<FlowStep>>();
 let c: Observable<Array<WorkFlow>> = Observable.create((obs: Observer<Array<WorkFlow>>) => {
            this._wfService.getWorkFlows(0, 50).subscribe((data: Array<WorkFlow>) => {
                this.workFlows = data;
                obs.next(this.workFlows);
                this.generateStatus();
            }, (err: Response) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        });
        this.workFlowsOb = c.shareReplay(1);
     }




generateStatus(): void {
        this.workFlows.forEach(m=>{
        // actions
        this.fileStatus.push(status);
});
```

^ `ngOnChange` doenst call on this line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will not work on `push` because this won't create a new reference of the `fileStatus` object so Angular will not fire ChangeDetection. So what you can do, for ex. create a new object every time you push:

```
this.fileStatus.push(status);
this.fileStatus = this.fileStatus.slice();
```